# ExpandedList inside a Fragment

Tags: android

How to put Expanded List inside a Fragment Tab?

I have 3 fragments in one page, The 2nd Fragment consist of two tabs,I want to put an expanded List inside the second tab.please help ,Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong in assuming that you are using ListFragment to show the lists. If you want to use a `ExpandableListView` you are going to have to implement it yourself inside a normal `Fragment` since there is no `ExpandableListFragment` implemented in the APIs.

Here is a link to Android's documentation on how to implement it: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) sure it will help :)